# QBContent.uploadFileTask error

Tags: android, quickblox-android

```
com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException: MethodNotAllowed
04-12 18:11:49.125 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBXmlParser.parse(QBXmlParser.java:33)
04-12 18:11:49.135 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.core.Query$VersionEntityCallback.completedWithResponse(Query.java:387)
04-12 18:11:49.135 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.core.Query.completedWithResponse(Query.java:271)
04-12 18:11:49.135 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage(HttpRequestRunnable.java:37)
04-12 18:11:49.145 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-12 18:11:49.145 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-12 18:11:49.145 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
04-12 18:11:49.145 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 18:11:49.145 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-12 18:11:49.155 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-12 18:11:49.155 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-12 18:11:49.155 17022-17022/com.app W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 18:12:05.342 17022-17022/com.app W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Please help me with the above error. I am trying to upload an image for user via gallary/camera
but getting following error. Even I tried the example mentioned on link
https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-android#Upload_file
but could not found any way.

> I am using QuickBlox Android SDK 2.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Let update your Android SDK to version 2.6.1, it will work well

Comment: what changes it will require